# Liquibase Diff Multiple Schema's

Tags: liquibase

I am using Liquibase (3.4.1) diffChangeLog to diff two PostgreSQL databases. Recently our tables have been divided into multiple schema's (in both databases). I tried these parameters (excluding url, driver, username, password) to try and get diffChangeLog to work:

```
defaultSchemaName=a
--referenceDefaultSchemaName=a
--schemas=a,b,c,d
--includeSchema=true
```

The result is a change log in which all objects in the database are being dropped. This is obviously not correct. It seems like Liquibase does not use the proper schema's to diff the objects.

Do I have the right configuration?

Comment: It seems this is [a bug](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2615).